# Writing to file and retrieving the contents of file

Tags: android, file

Hii I have been trying a  lot to retrieve contents of a file.My intention is to write some contents to a file and get them back as text view when a button is clicked. I have written some code but unfortunately, it is not working.Can any one help me.thanks in adv

```
public class Writing_to_fileActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public EditText edit;
    public Button btn, read;
    public TextView tv;
    public String str;
    public FileOutputStream fOut;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                str = edit.getText().toString();
                try {
                    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                     fOut= openFileOutput("Bharath.txt",
                            MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);                      
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);                      
                    osw.write(str);                     
                    osw.flush();                        
                    osw.close();                                            
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }       
        }); 
        read =(Button)findViewById(R.id.read);
        read.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fOut));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.append(line);
                        text.append('\n');
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tet);
                tv.setText(text);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working? Are you getting an Exception or is it just not doing what you expect?

Comment: what is the problem, be specific... add some logs. or in out result..

Comment: I did not get the text view.i.e., the whole code is running properly, but the text view is not appearing after my click of the button

Comment: Is there any FileReader constructor that accepts OutputStream ??..If there is...then WOW!, I dint kn that....!

Comment: no I dont include any constructor there..

Comment: I got the position where there is the chance of getting the rror it is at the line
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fOut));
The control is not moving after this line..Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Define your file again as

```
FileInputStream fIn;
```

and set the file input stream to your file

```
fIn=openFileInput("Bharath.txt");
```

Then set the buffer reader to read from the stream:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fIn));
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code in my app hope this help

write

```
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/text");
        if (!path.exists()){path.mkdirs();} 

        try{
        File text = new File(path,"text.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(text);
        writer.append(edit.getText());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
                   }
               catch////
```

read

```
            File txt = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/text");
    File file = new File(txt,"text.txt");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        if(file.exists())    {   
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
                            tv.setText(Text);
            }
             //catch
```

Comment: Dude the parser is not moving after the line in writ
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(text); 

and in reading after the line 
File text = new File(path,"text.txt");

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following line...

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fOut));
```

with

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Bharath.txt"));
```

and then try...

Comment: Inside your while loop, where you are reading from the file.....try printing "line" on the console....this will help you in debugging...

Comment: the condition in the while will read and check it. The parser is not checking from the line BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fOut));

Comment: Replace your fOut with "Bharath.txt".....Just before appending "line".....write System.out.println(line);......and see if it prints that line.....

Comment: I mean just while reading the file use the fileName("Bharath.txt")....writing to the file looks good to me...

Comment: Done the same but did not get the requirement dude

Comment: There isn't any error and at the same time there is'nt any output.. This is what I dont understand my friend

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6962/discussion-between-bharath-gupta-and-shashank-kadne)

Comment: Sorry for late reply...try printing the stackTrace in your second try...catch...i see that its empty...

Comment: yes its empty.. I dont understand how to proceed here after to diaply

Comment: Please copy content of your second anonymous innerclass setOnClickListener...in the comment....

Comment: I am sorry.. I did not understood what u have said... can u plz be a little bit clear for me

Comment: Add the whole try catch block where you are reading from the file...to this comment box...so that i can read it.....

Comment: read =(Button)findViewById(R.id.read);read.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(View v) {
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
try {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fOut));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
text.append(line);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
}
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tet);
tv.setText(text);
}
});

Comment: tried butin vain, It did not work dude. I have written @e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Can you check what br.ready() returns ? Print it just below "BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fOut));
"

Comment: Dude, change your readers and writers to something like this....BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Bharath.txt",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)));...and BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("Bharath.txt")));

Comment: I did not get any change even I have changed. Sry for the trouble but could u give your complete solution to bharathkumar8231@gmail.com

Comment: Sure...it will take some time...till then you can hv a look here.....http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidFileSystem/article.html